# Where should I place the "Stay signed in" checkbox?

Tags: gui-design, login, checkboxes

I'm new to this community and it might be that this question is off-topic; feel free to suggest me to delete this post, if so.

I've gazed at this OAuth pre-login window I created for quite a while, of which I'm pleased. Except for the "Stay signed in" checkbox that looks misplaced.

I just can't pinpoint what's wrong here.

[image: Google Login]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome,

no your question is not off-topic even though it would fit into https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ as well.

From an aesthetic point of view i would move the Google Sign In Button more to the top and center everything vertically.

Place the "Stay signed in"-button below the Google Sign In button.

You could change the Sign In-button text to "Sign In with Google" just to make it more clear (many people don't read and just scan so they might overlook the text above), even tho most people will recognize this option, it makes the button a bit wider which makes it overall a bit more visually pleasing.

Here is a quick draft of what i mean:
[image]

Comment: Isn't the Google logo itself recognizable instead of "Sign in with Google"?

Comment: Depends on the users.. as i said this would be optional and since it does not look like he has space issues i don't see the benefit of risking it by only presenting the icon.

Answer (score 3):

**This is strictly based on my personal perception.**

Well, if it were me, I would make the "*Sign In*" button a little bigger, because when compared to "*Stay signed in*" checkbox, the former has a higher priority and thus, should be made more prominent, don't you think?

[image]

But then again, all this is a matter of opinion. I believe that the UX should be influenced by the importance of the functionality.

Here, the main function is to sign in, and if it were me, the maximum visual prominence would be given to the sign in button.

The stay signed-in checkbox should ideally come below the sign in button, not beside it.